# Sync Google contact Data return 403 FOrbidden after 15Th aughust

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

My app always worked properly after August 15th when sync contacts with **google returns 403 Forbidden**. The scope inside google console for Project is the follow:

- email
- profile
- openid
- ../auth/contacts (verified)

The app using GData Contacts The scopes https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/

I Have upload a sample in c# for see the problem

http://www.fasthomestore.it/googleSended.zip

For compile you must specified the CliendID, ClientSecret and application name in class1_contacts.cs

**The error is the follow**

```
403 Forbidden  
Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=99999"
code: 403, The caller does not have permission 
status : PERMISSION_DENIED
```

Please can someone help me?

Comment: We usually see this error if the Contacts API is disabled for the given project. You can check it directly here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/contacts.googleapis.com/overview.  If this page shows an Enable button, click it and check your application again.

Comment: Thank's for answer, but the API is enabled, the APP working for more years, now after 15th Aughust is blocked but i don't have change my app code or configuration. Please you have other idea for fix this issue ?